# Viewing the standard library implementations

Tags: c++, c

I'm using VS-Code on windows. And I'm using `rust-analyzer` extension. It also works for C/C++. When I want to view the implementation of a standard library function, it takes me to the function's declaration.

For example:

When I try to view the `malloc` function, it takes me to

```
_Check_return_ _Ret_maybenull_ _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size)
_ACRTIMP _CRTALLOCATOR _CRT_JIT_INTRINSIC _CRTRESTRICT _CRT_HYBRIDPATCHABLE
void* __cdecl malloc(
    _In_ _CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW size_t _Size
    );
```

this is located in `corecrt_malloc.h` file. But this is just a declaration. I'm unable to find the actual implementation for any std function. I don't want to go and search files manually. Is there an easier way to do this?

Note:
`findstr` doesn't work for me. If I type, for example, `malloc`, it finds every `malloc` call.

Comment: FYI:  https://github.com/microsoft/STL

Comment: Yep but I'm trying to do it on my local pc, it is way more convenient @Wyck

Comment: The source of the implementation might not be shipped. In an SDK it might be that the implementation is in a shared library file (.so).

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:microsoft/STL.git`

Comment: git clone not working for you?

Comment: Then? How can I find the implementation place without searching for it manually?

Comment: FYI, the standard library implementation is different for the C and C++ languages.  For example, C++ has `std::cin` and `std::string`, and the C language doesn't.  So, which single language are you focusing on?  Please remove the other tag.

Comment: Both languages. @ThomasMatthews

Comment: _"How can I find the implementation place without searching for it manually?"_ - Most IDEs have some sort of "goto definition" that you can click to goto the definition.

Comment: As I pointed out above, goto definition takes me to the declaration. Not to implementation. @TedLyngmo

Comment: There's no requirement for a compiler to come with the source of the standard libraries. You probably don't have it so there's no way for the IDE to find it.

Comment: Clone the repo and then use `git grep`. Shouldn't take long to find what you need.

Comment: @Wyck does that also contain the C runtime implementation?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Windows SDK installed, look for the file (change the version if necessary):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\heap\malloc.cpp
```

You will notice `malloc` calls `_malloc_base`, which is in `malloc_base.cpp` in the same directory. `_malloc_base` then calls `HeapAlloc`. And since this one is part of Windows system DLLs (namely `kernel32.dll`), I fear you won't find its source code. See also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc).

Answer (score 2):

The actual definition of the function is almost certainly not there. It is compiled and distributed inside the C runtime library.